# "mkdir foo; svn mv * foo"

Tags: shell, directory, rename, wildcards

I often want to do some variant of this idiom:

```
$ mkdir 2010
$ svn mv * 2010
```

Of course, I get an error because the glob matches 2010 as well:

```
svn: Cannot copy path '2010' into its own child '2010/2010'
```

Is there a way to replace `"svn mv * 2010"` with a different one-liner that does the right thing?

Comment: This is not a question specific to svn, it applies to vanilla `mv` as well. However, with `mv`, `mv * newdir` works for me, albeit with an error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Under ksh, bash or zsh:

```
svn mv !(2010) 2010
```

Under bash, you need to run `shopt -s extglob` first (put it in your `~/.bashrc`). Under zsh, you need to run `setopt -o ksh_glob` first (put it in your `~/.zshrc`).

This doesn't move dot files (files whose name begins with `.`). If you have some, move them separately. Take care to exclude the `.svn` directory if you have one. In ksh or zsh:

```
svn mv !(2010) .!(svn) 2010
```

In bash, this is more complicated because you also need to explicitly exclude `.` and `..`.

```
svn mv !(2010) .!(svn|.|) 2010
```

---

Zsh also has a different, shorter syntax, which requires running `setopt -o extended_glob` first (again, put this in `~/.zshrc`):

```
svn mv {^,}2010
```

First brace expansion comes into play, resulting in `svn mv ^2010 2010`. Then the pattern `^2010` (a shortcut for “files matching `*` but not `2010`”) is expanded.

If you have a `.svn` directory, you'll need to exclude it from the move. This is ok by default, as `.svn` is not matched by `*` (it's a dot file). However, there are complications:

- If you've set the `glob_dots` option, you'll need to exclude `.svn` as well:

  ```
  svn mv !(2010|.svn) 2010             # requires setopt ksh_glob
  svn mv *~(.svn|2010) 2010            # requires setopt extended_glob
  ```
- If you have dot files and you haven't set `glob_dots`, you'll need to move them separately:

  ```
  svn mv {^,}2010
  svn mv .*~.svn 2010
  ```

  To do it in one go:

  ```
  svn mv *~(.svn|2010)(D) 2010
  ```

Another way that would work in zsh in this case (if you have no subdirectories) is `svn mv *(.D) 2010`, to match only regular files (`.`) including dot files (`D`).

Answer (score 3):

ZSH has a helpful glob operator to match everything except a given name, `^`. So this would work (but it's ZSH specific, and you need to `setopt extendedglob` first):

```
$ svn mv ^2010 2010
```

Comment: I've known about the `!()` syntax that works with `zsh`. How does the `^` syntax differ? It doesn't work in my shell, what option would I need to set to enable it?

Comment: @Caleb Sorry, I thought it was on by default, but apparently you need to `setopt extendedglob`. I didn't know about `!()`, it sounds like a more cross-shell way to do it

Comment: `svn mv {^,}2010` to avoid typing the directory name twice

Answer (score 0):

If your files have “tame” names (no whitespace, unprintable characters or `\[?*`):

```
svn mv $(ls | grep -vx 2010) 2010
```

Comment: Files cannot be trusted to have "tame" names. Ever :) The shell glob solutions presented for bash and zsh neatly sidestep this issue.